# Python PHP SOA design

Tags: php, python, soa

I am in the planning stage of a moderately big application -- and after some discussions and meetings, my colleges and i have reached a conclusion that we'll be using SOA for this App. Here is the brief plan...

a 4-tier architecture..

```
|-------- database (NoSQL + SQL polyglot store)                --------|
|-------- python for all the heavy business logic              --------|
|-------- php would talk to python using SOA and render HTML   --------|
|-------- front-end (html+css+js)                              --------|
```

- we will have two instances of python (2 machines) one will be tornado server for real time collaborations and the other will serve the non-realtime business logic.
- PHP will talk to the non-realtime machine via well defined RESTful interfaces.
- realtime collaboration machine will directly talk to JS client in the browser

My questions are...

- do you see any immediate flaws in the design?
- what is the best transport medium you recommend for RESTful communication  -- XML, JSON, or [protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) (protobuf is used by google)
- do you think caching between Python and PHP layers is a good idea? PHP will not do any direct DB communication -- only through Python.
- anything else you need to point out?

--- ***UPDATE*** ---

Although I am not allowed to reveal the specifics of the app, I want to tell that the app is a highly
collaborative in nature and deals with a lot of editing of text in the browser. Something like Google Docs -- but not exactly.

The reason PHP layer is important is because...

We need to keep the Python layer completely independent of HTML templating. That layer shoudn't
even know that we're building a Web App.
The reason for this is that we have multiple templates. The html for advanced browser is fairly complex
with lot of controls, mouse gesture events and ajax.
The template for older browsers (IE-6,7 FF-2,3, etc.)
is simple and "read only" -- with no ajax interactions.

There is also a third set of templates that we need to use for the Adobe AIR component of the app.
The company also has planned to release the mobile & desktop versions of the app if it turns to be
successful.

For this reason, we just can't afford to introduce HTML at the python layer.
What we can do is replace PHP layer with another python layer (with django or something)
to handle the templating. But we think we can handle templates better in PHP --
because it is so good for templating. We are NOT going to add any complex logic -- just
the presentation mechanics.

Comment: Not a "flaw" but can you do without mixing Python and PHP at the front end level? There are several templating engines for Python with higher performance and security track record than PHP has e.g. Jinja 2. Having no PHP would simplify the technology stack and make it easier to maintain.

Comment: All XML based communication protocols tend to add bloat and latency - avoid them if possible.

Comment: We can NOT forgo the PHP layer -- see the updated question for reasons :) thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few thoughts on your ideas:  As Mikko's comment mentions, the PHP layer seems superfluous.  It's not clear what function it will actually implement, specifically in terms of the abstraction it provides on top of the service layer.  Modern application design is tending towards implementing the UI in javascript+html.  Since you're already commited to exposing the business logic via http, it must also do all of the input validation and auth/auth already, so the php middleware just won't have much of a job to do.

An actual RESTful service doesn't dictate the outputs it supports, rather, it does its best to satisfy the `Accept-Content-Type` from the request.  In Python at least, it's usually easiest to support json.  Protobuf is still pretty young, so unless you really need the strict typing it provides, i'd keep away from it.  XML is useful, though, from a self-descriptive point of view, and might be preferred if the front and back ends are being developed in isolation.